# How to pass a recived message to a AsyncTask - Android

Tags: java, android

I've a newbie question about Android about something I want to do that I don't know how to do. I've added code to a button that when i click on it, it send a UDP message to a device:

```
class SendUDPMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {
            String udpMsg = "hello world from UDP client " + UDP_SERVER_PORT;

            DatagramSocket ds = null;

            try
            {
                ds = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
                DatagramPacket dp;
                dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, UDP_SERVER_PORT);
                ds.send(dp);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ds != null)
                {
                    ds.close();
                }
            }

            return "Done";
        }
```

Button use a Thread created using AsyncTask and send UDP message. That works well, but I need also something like: Send Message - Wait and resend message until recived response. If I have something in background that handle recived messages, how I can pass recived message to this task so it can stop?

p.s. I'm new to Java and Android, I've programmed in low level C so passage to OOP is hard, please be kind.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramPacket pack);
```

it blocks the thread until a packet is received. 
Take a look at:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#receive(java.net.DatagramPacket)